# Emulator does not appear - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have installed **Android studio 1.0.1** in **Windows 7**. After installing, created new project and created new device in AVD manager. When I try to launch AVD, it is giving following error. Googled about this error and tried different solutions but didnt help. Tried launching AVD by enabling/disabling Host GPU, installed latest Java, re-entered JAVA path in environment variables and downloaded System image of x86 but didnt help. Let me know if anyone has faced similar issue with Android Studio.

```
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: device fd:524
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add a bit more info about your runtime (Windows version etc.).

Comment: I see a close vote, but this is about setting up a development environment. That should be on topic here, unless something has changed significantly in that regard. (and welcome, Shashi, almost forgot :) )